# SSH - problem with connection

Tags: networking, ssh

I have two computers, this computers have the same routing table (inet addr is also the same).How can i connect from first computer via ssh to second computer.

Comment: "inet addr is also the same": does that mean you have two computers in one net with the same IP address? This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

On the remote host, make sure OpenSSH server is installed:

```
apt-get install openssh
```

Still on the remote host, make sure service is running:

```
systemctl enable ssh
```

Having identified the IP of your remote host, log in using:

```
ssh username_on_remote_host@remote_host_ip_addr
```